# OpenCV accuracy measurement

Tags: opencv

I am wondering, are there tools in OpenCV (or compatible) that I can use to evaluate accuracy of the ML algorithms? For instance, for face recognition it is common to evaluate a method with EER and HTER criteria, plot ROC and DET curves etc.

Most ML toolkits have built-in tools to evaluate their performance (in terms of accuracy), is there any in OpenCV?

Comment: No, you have to code it yourself. If you're using python then you can easily draw your charts with matplotlib, in C++ is more difficult (I usually save all needed data in CSV, and plot them using matlab)